# Should version be bumped in a merge commit?

Tags: git, release-management

I am using git branching model described in [this post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

In case the version number is included in code (like in `rubygems`), in which commit should I change the number? I suppose not feature branch, since a release version somehow belong to `master` branch.

BTW If it should be changed in a merge commit, are there some command to modify the contents before merge actually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the article through, it's explained.

The version changes just before you merge back into `master`, via a `release-` branch.

There are no actual commands for this, but I can imagine a simple bash script that'll alter the content of the file in a specific place to change the version number only.